# What material used in soil based microbial fuel?

Tags: electricity, biology, electrochemistry

I have seen from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_fuel_cell#Soil-based_microbial_fuel_cell) that there are soil based microbial fuel which need only anode and cathode while soil itself could act as proton exchange filter

But what kind of other material it needed? Such as anode and cathode. And what formula needed to calculate voltage? Is it the same as galvanic cell?

My country has no microbial fuel cell kit for sell so I want to know to construct with raw material

Comment: To be very honest with you... that Wikipedia article is highly questionable. Science education should stress easily understandable principles and demonstrate them with SIMPLE experiments. Biological proton exchange membranes are anything but simple and a true understanding requires enormously complex science experiments. What they are showing you on Wikipedia (and the link to that commercial kit company, cough,...)... that's not good science education by any standard.  If you stick two different metals into soil, the soil will act as an electrolyte, whether it's dead or alive.

Comment: @CuriousOne I too was skeptic that it should not be that simple. I also want to know how to distinguish between galvanic voltage and microbe voltage. The point may be that, will soil and microbe be able to filter proton?

Comment: "Galvanic voltage" is a somewhat historic term. Today we have the well defined term "electrochemical potential", instead. All chemical systems, biological or abiotic, have electrochemical potentials. Proton pumps use an active biological mechanism to convert chemical energy into a potential difference and current, but that's a non-trivial science problem that belongs into biology. Physics can't say much about it, apart from the fact that thermodynamics applies, of course. For teaching purposes in school I would avoid these systems at all cost.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's why I choose the word galvanic. Because both galvanic and microbial is electrochemical potential and I want to know how to distinguish them in action. And this problem relate to physics in question of proton filtering and  material for anode and cathode

Comment: There is nothing to distinguish without a complex experiment. Chemical potential is chemical potential, no matter how complex the system is that creates it. If you can insert two electrodes made from equal metals on either side of the bacterial membrane and you can biochemically modulate the proton pump, then you have a pump specific signal, but that's a graduate or post-graduate research experiment, I am afraid. Can you do it in high-school? Sure... with the best and brightest of students, but you may want to repost this in biology for the details.